# is/are expected to land on Mars

Tags: singular-vs-plural

In the following sentence, is the singular **is** correct? It's from CNN.

> In 2022, the European Rosalind Franklin rover and Russian surface platform Kazachok will launch and **is** expected to land on Mars in 2023.